# Software not opening in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, ide

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS installed in my system. Suddenly some software (phpStorm, System Monitor and Skype) is not being opening also, I have tried re-install but still not working.

Trace:

- Click to open any software.
- This will show the process to open the software(At activity bar).
- Suddenly process stops execution without any error.

Can anyone help me what's going wrong?

Thanks advance!

Comment: Your title says 18.04, but the tags shows 14.

Comment: Yeah, it is minor issues, but could be confusing to people.

Comment: Try launching it from terminal, from there you can either paste the output or Googling it. I usually do that, and quickly found a fix.

Comment: What the three applications that aren't able to be launched have in common is that they are all snap packages.  Try reinstalling snapd. `sudo apt purge snapd && sudo apt install snapd && sudo snap refresh`